# how to skip installation of subpackage

Tags: aem

I have added ACS Commons as subpackage in my project pom file. I would like to have possibility to skip installation of subpackage based on parameter, this is because I do not want to install ACS commons every time i install my project. For this I do not find possibility to add skip parameter

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <group>${package.group}</group>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <root>/etc/packages/adobe/consulting</root>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <subPackages>
                    <subPackage>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core.wcm.components.all</artifactId>
                        <filter>false</filter>
                        <skip>true</skip> // something like this
                    </subPackage>
                </subPackages>            
              </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to ignore specific packages. You need to add a section within the configuration tags called `subPackageHandlingEntries`

See the documentation here: [jackrabbit](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault-package-maven-plugin/generate-metadata-mojo.html#subPackageHandlingEntries)

To add a global ignore your configuration would look like this:

```
<subPackageHandlingEntries>
    <entry>
        <option>IGNORE</option>
    </entry>
</subPackageHandlingEntries>
```

But you can also specify group and package names:

```
<subPackageHandlingEntries>
    <entry>
        <option>IGNORE</option>
        <groupName>adobe/consulting</groupName>
        <packageName>acs-aem-commons-content</packageName>
    </entry>
</subPackageHandlingEntries>
```